# i am trying to make it so when you click one of the drop down selections, it will add to a list, here is the code of one of our drop down buttons

Tags: javascript, list, button

We are trying to code a way to click one of the vegetable selections and have it be added to a list at the side of the page

```
  <div class="container">
  <h2>
  </h2>
  <p></p> 

  <div class="dropdown">
  <div  id="dropdown" style="position:fixed; left:400px; top:120px;"  class="main">
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">Vegetable
<span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
  <li role="presentation"><a role="menutype" tabindex="1" href="#">Carrots</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="2" href="#">Tomatos</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="3" href="#">Lettuce</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="4" href="#">Peas</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="5" href="#">Green Beans</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="6" href="#">Potatoes</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="7" href="#">Corn</a></li>
  <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
</ul>

 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What javascript have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new function and add this to the dropdown:

```
onChange="OnSelectedIndexChange()"
```

And modify this function to your needs. Upon new selection on the dropdown, it will append the ***li*** item to your other list (***ul***). Maybe you need to change the attribute you want to get the text instead of the value.

```
//function for changed selection
function OnSelectedIndexChange()
{
document.getElementById('myListOfItems').append("<li>"+document.getElementById('dropdown').value+"</li>");
}
```